# Why specify address of variable in ASM instead of just copying it into register?

Tags: gcc, assembly, sse, simd

In my quest to learn assembly (using GCC on x86_64), I have come across some SSE examples where instead of just copying a C variable into a register, the address is copied in to EAX instead. Why do that when you can just do this:

```
typedef float v4sf __attribute__((vector_size(16)));

typedef union {
    v4sf v;
    float f[4];
} Vec4;

Vec4 vector.v = (v4sf){ 64.1,128.2,256.3,512.4 };
float blah = 2.2;

__asm__("movups %0, %%xmm0 \n\t"
    "movups %1, %%xmm1 \n\t"
    "shufps $0x00, %%xmm1, %%xmm1 \n\t"
    "mulps %%xmm1, %%xmm0 \n\t"
    "movups %%xmm0, %0 \n\t"
    : "+m"(vector)
    : "m"(blah)
    : "%xmm0","%xmm1"
);
```

Does copying the vector into xmm0 (rather than keeping it in memory) cause a performance hit?

Here is an example of what I'm talking about (it's Intel syntax):

```
void powf_schlickSSE(const float * a, const float b, float * result){

    __asm {
        mov         eax, a              //load address of vector
        movss       xmm0, dword ptr [b] //load exponent into SSE register
        movups      xmm1, [eax]         //load vector into SSE register
        shufps      xmm0, xmm0, 0       //shuffle b into all floats
        movaps      xmm2, xmm1          //duplicate vector
        mov         eax, result         //load address of result
        mulps       xmm1, xmm0          //xmm1 = a*b
        subps       xmm0, xmm1          //xmm0 = b-a*b
        addps       xmm0, xmm2          //xmm2 = b-a*b+a
        rcpps       xmm0, xmm0          //xmm1 = 1 / (b-a*b+a)
        mulps       xmm2, xmm0          //xmm0 = a * (1 / (b-a*b+a))
        movups      [eax], xmm2         //store result
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the original code/assembly that has the behavior you describe? It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sure, I added an example in Intel syntax.

Comment: That assembly is definitely far from optimal. Nowadays it's preferred to just use intrinsics unless you are sure you can beat the compiler.

Comment: You're asking if it's slower to use the xmm registers than to have the vector in memory?

Comment: Is there a pow() function that will operate on vectors? If not, then don't I have to write it manually?

Comment: @Synthetix: Even if you have to write it manually, why use asm instead of sse intrinsics for the appropriate sse commandos? That way the compiler won't miss out on optimizing it. And I'm still not sure what your question is about. Are you asking if it's faster to load a variable into a register before using it instead of using instructions which add a variable loaded from memory to an register?

Answer (score 0):

I can see multiple reasons

- MSVC (which that Intel-syntax code comes from, right?) doesn't support passing __m128 values into assembly blocks, or at least the version the code was written for didn't. Or maybe that version didn't support SSE at all except via inline assembly.
- The rest of the program didn't deal with vector types, so passing by pointer was the simplest solution.